# vue close page function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

how to implement closing a page through a function in vue js

by example

configured routing

```
{
    path: '/example',
    component: Layout,
    redirect: '/example/list',
    name: 'Example',
    meta: {
      title: 'example',
      icon: 'example'
    },
children: [
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: () => import('@/views/example/create'),
    name: 'CreateArticle',
    meta: { title: 'createArticle', icon: 'edit' }
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id(\\d+)',
    component: () => import('@/views/example/edit'),
    name: 'EditArticle',
    meta: { title: 'editArticle', noCache: true },
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: () => import('@/views/example/list'),
    name: 'ArticleList',
    meta: { title: 'articleList', icon: 'list' }
  }]
},
```

when I go to ArticleList.vue, I open the list, go there to the authoring / editing country -> a new member opens (the list page remains open in the tab next to it), after submitting the form in CreateArticle.vue, the CreateArticle.vue page should close

Tried through destroy () As a result, the content of the page is cleaned, and the page itself remains (but empty), you have to close the page through X

Comment: Have you already read the [documentation on `Window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)?

Comment: how about using router.push, and redirect back to articlelist?

Comment: nope, not need close site, just close CreateArticle after sending form, and redirect to List.vue - redirect i'm doing, -> can't close component